# Jquery ui datepicker on iphone?

Tags: jquery, iphone, datepicker

JQuery ui datepicker wont work on mobile safari. Any workaround or fallback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is currently being tested on Mobile devices, not sure if it is jQuery UI as well (John Resig's Tweets come in handy).

So until it becomes available for mobile devices, you could look up other JavaScript datepickers as one fallback.

Or do 3 drop down boxes as use JavaScript to combine the to make the full date.

Some usefull link that might help you:

[Webkit spinning wheel](http://cubiq.org/spinning-wheel-on-webkit-for-iphone-ipod-touch)

[Mobile Datepicker](http://extjstutorial.com/article-mobile-datepicker)

[Yahoo YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/calendar/)

Comment: ... a pity you can't use the iPhone's native datepicker, even with HTML5 type="date"

Comment: Yeah true. Mobile safari doesn't support much Html5 elements at the moment, but when it does that would be cool.

Comment: Updated my answer. Found some links that might help you. And Should work on Browsers and/or Mobile browsers

Answer (score 1):

Well what you could try is to enable users to select their date trough 3 dropdown boxes. one for the years, one for the months and one for the days. Make sure your years range is wide enough to support all ages ;)

This way if their javascript isn't working correctly they can always select the date trough dropdowns.

something like this:

[alt text http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/8918/dateexample.png](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/8918/dateexample.png)

Comment: Always check the year part... I tried to order some ram from crucial last year, and their credit card end date drop down didn't go high enough for my card, so I couldn't buy it.

Comment: I think'll just use the placeholder Attribute from HTML 5 as a fallback (works on iphone) and try to validate the entered date afterwards

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so much into this rating business yet